# How can i disable the event listener? or having a stop button for it function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

please help me have a button to stop,pause or disable the function of the accelerometer? Here is my code thanks.

#### Accelerometer Readings

```
<script>

function init() {

  var accelerometer = document.getElementById('accelerometer');

  if(window.DeviceMotionEvent) {

  window.addEventListener('devicemotion', function(event) {

  var x = parseInt(event.accelerationIncludingGravity.x);

  var y = parseInt(event.accelerationIncludingGravity.y);

  var z = parseInt(event.accelerationIncludingGravity.z);

  var acce = 'Acceleration:<br />';

  acce += 'x: ' + x +'<br />y: ' + y + '<br />z: ' + z + ;

  accelerometer.innerHTML = acce;

     });
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Provide a named function reference to `.addEventListener()` then use name of function at `.removeEventListener()`

```
function handleAccelerationEvent(event) {

  var x = parseInt(event.accelerationIncludingGravity.x);

  var y = parseInt(event.accelerationIncludingGravity.y);

  var z = parseInt(event.accelerationIncludingGravity.z);

  var acce = 'Acceleration:<br />';

  acce += 'x: ' + x +'<br />y: ' + y + '<br />z: ' + z + ;

  accelerometer.innerHTML = acce;

}

function init() {

  var accelerometer = document.getElementById('accelerometer');

  if(window.DeviceMotionEvent) {

    window.addEventListener('devicemotion', handleAccelerationEvent);
  }
}
```

```
// remove `devicemotion` event referencing `handleAccelerationEvent` function
window.removeEventListener("devicemotion", handleAccelerationEvent)
```

Comment: can you sir give me a complete code? I'm really having a hard time fixing it cause I'm new to javascript. 
thanks,

Comment: @Ronnel.D _"How can i disable the event listener? or having a stop button for it function?"_ `<button id="stop">remove device motion event</button><script>function removeDeviceMotionEvent() {window.removeEventListener("devicemotion", handleAccelerationEvent)};document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", removeDeviceMotionEvent)</script>`

Comment: I have put your code sir and i added a function for the removeEventlistener and also a button for it. 
and it is not working.
the Accelerometer readings are not working..
please help me
    function stop(){
      window.removeEventListener("devicemotion", handleAccelerationEvent)
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="init()">
    <center><div id="accelerometer">
      No device motion data    <!--Displays when the device does not support a devicemotion event.--><br>
    </div>
    <div>
    <button onclick="stop()" id="Btn">STOP</button>
    </div>

Comment: I tried your code sir but the accelerometer readings are not working on my phone.

Comment: "it is not working"
is the readings of the accelerometer every time i move my phone.

Comment: _"I tried your code sir but the accelerometer readings are not working on my phone."_ That is not original Question. Original Question is _"
How can i disable the event listener? or having a stop button for it function?"_

Comment: sir would that be okay if you would give me your FB account or Gmail? so that we could have a better conversation. And so that i can attach some pics for you to see

Comment: The original question sir is  " How can i disable the event listener? and my accelerometer readings are working. then i tried your code for stop its not working.

Comment: Is `handleAccelerationEvent` defined?

Comment: yes sir its defined, cause i totally copied the code that you answered on my question

Comment: @Ronnel.D An example using `mousemove` event http://plnkr.co/edit/UeW53UtFEW1DeZenMeYg?p=preview

Comment: sir the link that you have given to me is very usefull.. but when i declare the accelerometer.innerHTML = event.acce; on the handleAccelerometer function its not giving me an output of values in my phone. but when i put the accelerometer.innerHTML = event.acce; on the function init it works properly but the button STOP is not working.
here is the code for you to see.
http://plnkr.co/edit/rdEMawUY86hws4fhdfqn?p=preview

Comment: @Ronnel.D The page should be loaded at `https:` protocol, when loaded at `http:` this message is logged at `console` `The devicemotion event is deprecated on insecure origins, and support will be removed in the future. You should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See goo.gl/rStTGz for more details.` . Also `accelerometer` `.innerHTML` was not set at version 1 of http://plnkr.co/edit/rdEMawUY86hws4fhdfqn?p=preview. See version 3 at same link

Comment: sir I'm done with my project because of you sir thank you so much for the help thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Method 1: Do not use an anonymous function for a listener: assign it to a variable, so that you can pass it to `removeEventListener`.

Method 2: Do not remove a listener; instead, have a flag that determines whether it is active or not. If it is not active at the top of the listener, return without any effect.

Comment: can you sir give me a complete code? I'm really having a hard time fixing it cause I'm new to javascript. thanks,